# Create an SQL query which allows only specific users to login

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am a newbie to SQL. I got stuck in this question.
I have 2 SQL tables: users with (name,userid), blacklistID  with (userid). I want to create a sql query that will only allow non-blacklisted users to login.
Any suggestions are highly welcomed. thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the `users` and `blacklist` tables together, and then check to make sure that a given user did not match the blacklist:

```
SELECT u.name, u.userid
FROM users u LEFT JOIN blacklist b
    ON u.userid = b.userid
WHERE u.name = 'username' AND b.userid IS NULL
```

If the above query returns a record for a given `username` then it means he is not blacklisted.

However, I think a better database design would be to add a column to your original `users` table (call it `isActive`) which will monitor whether or not a user's account has become inactive ("blacklisted").  In this case, you can do a simple query only on the `users` table to get what you need:

```
SELECT u.name, u.userid
FROM users u
WHERE u.name = 'username' AND u.isActive
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to return your condition in the form of a variable using:

```
SELECT
    u.userID,
    isOnBlackList=CASE WHEN b.userID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM 
   users u
   LEFT OUTER JOIN blacklistID b ON b.userID=u.userID
WHERE
   u.userID=@UserID
```

Or, If you wish to return an empty set or null to indicate "No UserID Exists" or "The user is invalid because on blacklist" then use a condition in  your where clause to exclude blacklist matches.

```
SELECT
    u.userID
FROM 
   users u
   LEFT OUTER JOIN blacklistID b ON b.userID=u.userID
WHERE
   b.userID IS NULL
   AND
   u.userID=@UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use stored procedure for this. However I supposed you want to call from you code:

In your code, you will have variable:

```
var userName
```

And below is the the sql query you want

```
'select 
   name,
   userid
from users u
left outer join blacklistID b on b.userid = u.userid
where b.userid is null
    and u.name =' + userName
```

The query will return a record if the login name is not blacklisted, otherwise it will not return anything